# Scrolling Issues on Android OS

Tags: android, jquery, mobile

so I'm having problems getting the screen to scroll when trying to view a site I'm working on, on an Android phone.  If you view the site: [CMB SOUND](http://cmbsound.net/temp) on a desktop browser, you'll see that I'm using anchor links within my navigation. So you aren't brought to an actual new page when you click a link. I'm using a jquery plugin to aid in doing this. Desktop works as it should, and Safari Mobile OS works pretty well, but on Android, the "pages" or content is cutoff at the bottom navigation dropdown, and the user can't scroll beyond it. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this in Android? Please let me know if I didn't explain myself well enough.   Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the problem you face? scolling your page on the android browser or your own application?

Comment: @RoystonPinto Thanks for your reply. The issue is when you visit the provided link on an android phone browser, you'll see that the content is getting cut off, and you aren't able to keep scrolling.

Comment: Anthony, i see no such issues on my Sony Xperia smartphone. Which is the phone you are seeing this issue with?

Comment: Well that is good to hear. Hopefully it's not on all android browsers, then. My test android phone is an HTC Eris Android 1.5/   webkit 3.1. Well crap. I'm going to have to try and find a good way to test in other Android versions.

Comment: Yes, i dont think with the latest android browsers such issues will be seen.

Comment: Well crap. I just rooted the phone, and updated to a newer version of Android, and there's still issues. Even worse now, actually.